# Success message in Django

Tags: python, django

In my django app I am taking form input.Once that form is validated I am displaying a success message with help of [Django Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/).

**Current State**

I am able to display a success message in the template after submission of form when I redirect it to same url(The url of the form itself)

My views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
    form_data = form.save()

    messages.success(request, 'Submited Successfully')
    return redirect('form-url')
```

**What I want**

Once the form is submitted I want to display a success message on the same page(`form-url`) and then I want to redirect to a new url `list-of-submitted-forms`.

For that I did something like this to my views.py

```
 if form.is_valid():
        form_data = form.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Submited Successfully')
        return redirect('list-of-submitted-forms')
```

**The problem I am facing**

I am redirecting to a new url.But without getting success message on the `form-url` page.Also again when I go to `form-url` page(By clicking a button which redirects to that url) the message of `'Submited Successfully'` is shown

My HTML/JS

```
<script>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
                    {% if message.tags == "success" %}
                         swal({text:"{{ message }}",icon: "success",timer: "4000",buttons: false})  
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
```

Comment: you can remove the `return redirect('list-of-submitted-forms')` inside your view,and let message shows up in the template with a link to redirect user to `list-of-submitted-forms` just by clicking. hide the form when you do that, or reset it

Comment: Means I should make changes in my template and as far as views.py is there I should stick with `redirect('form-url`) is that what you saying Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: post you html codes, i will do it with

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want to do, I'm showing you a way to do it with a `JsonResponse`.

**views**

```
from django.http import JsonRespon   
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse 

if form.is_valid():
    form_data = form.save()

    response = {'msg':'Submited Successfully',
                'url':reverse('list-of-submitted-forms'),
                'created':True}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

**js**

```
$("#your_form").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url:"URL",
        type:'POST',
        data:formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(data){
            if(data.created){
                alert(data.msg); // handle the message , till the user click ok, and redirect to data.url
                window.location.href = data.url;
            }
            else{
                $("your_form").html($("your_form",data));
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you please also give other ways of doing it.Also please let me know if you want anything else